# How can I set a specific value for an Entity property that is a primary key in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am attempting to create a new entity and save it back to the Database however I need to set a specific value for the ID column. When I call SaveChanges() however and the insert statement is generated it is automatically generating a new ID despite me specifying a value when I create and add the new entity to the current context.

If it helps any, the column currently has the StoreGeneratedPattern property set to "Identity" in both the SSDL and the CSDL content (I have checked this in the .edmx in XML).

Any idea on why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

If your property has `StoreGenerationPattern` set to `Identity` it says EF that the value will be always set in the database. You cannot change it. If it works it also means that your database is configured to automatically generate the ID for you.

If you want to set the value from application you must have `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `None` and your database must never generate the value. You will have to set the unique key value every time.